# Convert a string date into datetime in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01861

How can I convert this string date to datetime in oracle.

```
2011-07-28T23:54:14Z
```

Using this code throws an error:

```
TO_DATE('2011-07-28T23:54:14Z',  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

How can this be done?

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

**Update:-**

TO_DATE('2011-07-28T23:54:14Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')

I only see the date not time in the column

```
28-JUL-11
```

Comment: Your format doesn't have T and Z letters, or am I wrong? 
Try to parse 2011-07-28 23:54:14, if it will pass, then use regex to normalize your input strings.

Comment: @p.campbell but in my case. String date is in different format with t and z so is there any way to convert that directly to datetime format. Or I have to parse it to make it more clearer then convert that to datetime format..

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this:
`TO_DATE('2011-07-28T23:54:14Z',  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')`

Comment: It is working fine.. But I only see the Date not time in the oracle table.. The result that I got is 28-JUL-11 not the exact way I wanted.. Why is it happening? And I declare the dataType as date.

Comment: @RaihanJamal, that's just the default format for date.  The time is actually stored in that field as well.  You can see it using the TO_CHAR method.

Comment: what's wrong with this sytax  `TO_DATE('2011-10-25 21:48:01.585', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: Looks like it has milliseconds on the time as well.  If this format is in the same dataset as the item in the OP, you need to follow the previously given advice of standardizing your data.

Comment: @lining, It should be `TO_DATE('2011-10-25 21:48:01.585', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')`, FFn may have n=1..9, depending on the number of decimal places you have.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I had the same problem. I tried to convert '2017-02-20 12:15:32' varchar to a date with `TO_DATE('2017-02-20 12:15:32','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` and all I received was 2017-02-20 the time disappeared

My solution was to use `TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-02-20 12:15:32','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` now the time doesn't disappear.

Comment: That is probably only because of the display formatting of your SQL client.  An Oracle `DATE` may also include a time so `TO_DATE` will not necessarily drop the time portion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cast to char to see the date results

```html
 select to_char(to_date('17-MAR-17 06.04.54','dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```