# oracle date extraction from varchar field

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have dates in a table saved in varchar2 field, oracle database.

Example

6/30/2012 
6/30/2013

I'm trying to extract year. Any ideas for extracting year other than using substr function?

Comment: Never, ever store dates in a varchar column. You should migrate that to a proper `DATE` column as soon as possible.

Comment: `update yourtable set yourcolumn = to_date(yourcolumn,'dd/mm/yyyy')` should do the trick for you  ((That's assuming that you at least have your rows in the format you gave as an example))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a date, and then get the year using date functions:

[Convert a string date into datetime in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920637/convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-in-oracle)