# updating timestamp column with timestamp containing 'T'

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have timestamp column:

```
MAX_LOAD_DATE_TS  TIMESTAMP(6)
```

My `load_dates` comes formatted with T in between `date` and `time`.

```
2014-07-02T10:46:22
```

Is there a way to convert this to legit `timestamp` on oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed literals in the format string if they're double-quoted:

```
select to_timestamp('2014-07-02T10:46:22', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02T10:46:22','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
-------------------------------------------------------------
02-JUL-14 10.46.22.000000000
```

That works with `to_date()` as well as `to_timestamp()`, and with `to_char()` going the other way.

This is mentioned [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref406):

> **Punctuation and Character Literals in Datetime Format Models**
>
> You can include these characters in a date format model:
>
> - Punctuation such as hyphens, slashes, commas, periods, and colons
> - Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks
>
> These characters appear in the return value in the same location as
>   they appear in the format model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appropriate format string as well as the CAST function, as below:

```
SELECT 
        CAST(TO_DATE('2014-07-02T10:46:22', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP(6)) AS timestamp_value
FROM table;
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920637/convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-in-oracle)

Comment: You would need to double-quote the "T" in the format mask.  Otherwise, you'd get an ORA-01821 date format not recognized error since Oracle would try to interpret the T as one of the valid format masks.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, noted. I have updated the answer above.

Comment: Not sure why you'd use `cast(to_date() as timestamp)` rather than just `to_timestamp()`?

Comment: @AlexPoole Simply because I did not know better. Thank you for the note.