# Oracle SQL read timestamp from value in format YYYYMMDDThhmmss

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I'm trying to run the following query using Oracle SQL

```
select to_timestamp('2015/06/20T00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi.ss.ff') from dual;
```

However this gives me the following error

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

If I remove the "T" from the query it runs fine and returns the expected value, such as below.

```
select to_timestamp('2015/06/20 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi.ss.ff') from dual;
```

My question is, is there a way to convert the value containing the T into a timestamp or will the format always be incorrect?

Please let me know if you require and more information and I shall do my best to provide, thanks for your help.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24638426/266304), and there are many others...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just include the other characters within double quotes:

```
select to_timestamp('2015/06/20T00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd"T"hh24:mi.ss.ff') from dual
```

Comment: [Documentation reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref406) just for info.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `replace()`:

```
select to_timestamp(replace('2015/06/20T00:00:00', 'T', ' '),
                    'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi.ss.ff'))
from dual;
```