# Insert YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SEC.milliseconds timestamp to Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I need to insert the following date/time format to Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, DATETIMEREAD) VALUES (1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-06-03T11:28:07.571', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MM:SS')
```

I´m getting the following error:

```
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

How can I properly insert that ISO format (without time zone) to Oracle. The `DATETIMEREAD` column type is `TIMESTAMP(6)`

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24638426/266304)? Except it doesn't show the FF3 part of the format model...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`T` is not any Oracle timestamp element. You need to enclose it in double quotes. Also minutes are `MI` and you miss the fraction of second mask too. This should do the job:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, DATETIMEREAD) VALUES (1, TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-06-03T11:28:07.571', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'))
```