# Convert string to date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I'm trying to convert `string` column to `date` in Oracle SQL.

Here is my an example of value from the data:

```
'03/12/14 11:00:00'
```

Here is my query:

```
select to_date(A,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
from MyTable
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
03-DEC-14
```

Why my query return only the date but not the hour?

Comment: Because a date doesn't have an hours part? Try TIMESTAMP, maybe it works better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a string date into datetime in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920637/convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-in-oracle)

Comment: @jarlh: in Oracle `date` **does** have a time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks for the info! (I'm not an Oracle user, but I believe you've already found that out!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer) the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT is applied when a `DATE` value is *displayed*. To verify your current format you can run:

```
select value 
from nls_session_parameters 
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

To adjust this, run:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Then you should see the time as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to **DISPLAY** the datetime value. Use **TO_CHAR** along with proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

For example,

`select to_char(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;`

A **DATE** consists of both date and time portions. You just need to make sure you use appropriate format model to display it. Else, you end up with a format which depends on your **locale-specific NLS settings**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp

```
select to_timestamp(A, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS') from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query that returns the time portion of the date without having to alter the `nls_date_format` you can convert the date you got from the to_date function to a text representation (the default text representation is `dd-Mon-yy` as you found out) like this:

```
select to_char(
   to_date(A,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'),
   ''DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
from MyTable;
```

Ideally, column A of MyTable should have been defined as a date column instead of a varchar2 column.  There are several reasons to do that; data integrity, and better SQL optimization.