# How to convert number as date time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, date-formatting

I have a string as `08012016111512` where first two characters `08` is date, next two characters `01` is month, next four characters `2016` is year ,next two characters `11` is hour,next two characters `15` is minute and last two characters `12` is seconds. Suggest me how to convert above string as date time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920637/convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-in-oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **TO_DATE** function to explicitly convert the **string** literal into **DATE**.

```
to_date('08012016111512', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS')
```

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT to_date('08012016111512', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS') my_date FROM dual;

MY_DATE
-------------------
08-01-2016 11:15:12
```

NOTE : The alter session statement is only to display the date in desired format.