# conversion from string to particular date format in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

```
trunc(to_date('datefield1','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) 
between
trunc(to_date(to_char('05/18/2016 08:57','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'mm/dd/yyyy,hh24:mi:ss'))
and 
trunc(to_date(to_char('05/20/2016 08:57','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'mm/dd/yyyy,hh24:mi:ss'));
```

I need to convert the string '05/18/2016 08:57' into date

Comment: please format your code and add which error do you get and which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string date into datetime in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920637/convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-in-oracle)

Comment: @Mark, it looks like he is using Oracle. to_date is a function used in Oracle!

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values as `varchar`?

Comment: `to_char('05/18/2016 08:57','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` makes **no** sense whatsoever - you can shorten that to `''05/18/2016 08:57:00'`

Comment: sorry for the wrong requirement , I need to change "7 May, 2018 6:13:17 PM" that is the input into 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi'

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting a character string to a character string?  You can do:

```
trunc(to_date(datefield1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
    between trunc(to_date('05/18/2016 08:57', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy,hh24:mi:ss') and 
            trunc(to_date('05/20/2016 08:57', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

It is very strange to have `hh24:mi:ss` when the string itself has no seconds.  But Oracle allows it.

That said, I would write the logic as:

```
datefield1 >= date '2016-05-18' and
datefield1 < date '2016-05-21'
```

Comment: sorry for the wrong requirement , I need to change "7 May, 2018 6:13:17 PM" that is the input into 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi'